# Calculating Active Work Hours

Tags: sql, sql-server, time, time-complexity

We are busy with a report, to calculate the call rate for a client per user.
The user loads activities (calls) for all their activities / movements in the field on the system.  For example:  Meetings, Leave and more.

We want to calculate the Users effective hours in Field, ie Leave ect. excluded

Here is my query

```
SELECT  U.SubscriberID,
        U.Name,
        UT.EntityName,
        UT.Subject,
        UT.StartDate,
        UT.EndDate,
        UTT.Name AS TaskType,
        UT.UserTaskTypeID, 
        (Select Case when DatePart(DAY,UT.EndDate)<> DatePart(DAY,UT.StartDate) then Abs(DATEDIFF(Day, UT.StartDate, UT.EndDate) + 1) * 480 Else Abs(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, UT.StartDate, UT.EndDate)) End) AS OOF_Minutes
FROM [User] AS U
INNER JOIN UserTask AS UT ON U.UserID = UT.UserID
INNER JOIN UserTaskType AS UTT ON UT.UserTaskTypeID = UTT.UserTaskTypeID
WHERE      (U.SubscriberID = 261) AND (UT.UserTaskTypeID = 1401)
AND U.Name = 'Geoffrey Coetzee'
```

and here is my results:

[image]

How can I archive the following:

1. Calculate the duration in minutes between 2 dates (Start Date and End Date) using a factor for the users implied by Report to calculate the effective hours in the field.  (Number of Work Days * 8hrs/day - Out of Field (Task Type) hours
2. Divide number of activities (Not Out of Field Activities) with factor for Effective Call Rate

This is kinda confusing, but happy to explain business case behind it.

Comment: Depends on how the factor is "implied by Report".

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. But it sounds to me as if this is yet another gaps-and-islands question: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/18399.t-sql-gaps-and-islands-problem.aspx If so, you might want to add the appropriate tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands